# JPA SpannerRepository findById returns null in cloud spanner and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-spanner

I'll go straight to the point. I'm writing an API in Spring boot using Spring Data to connect to GCP Spanner in the back end. I have followed all required annotations, but when I call the findById on the repository interface it returns null with this error:
**at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy146.findById(unknown Source)**

Part of My Repository Interface is:

```
   public interface FileImportStatsRepository extends SpannerRepository<FileImportHistoryRecord, String>{
}
```

Part of My FileImportHistoryRecord DTO is:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "FileImportStats")
public class FileImportHistoryRecord {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(name = "FileImportId")
    private String fileImportId;
    
    .
    .
    .
```

Part of My Service class is:

```
@Service
public class FileErrorServiceImpl implements FileErrorService {

@Autowired
FileImportStatsRepository fileImportStatsRepository;

Optional<FileImportHistoryRecord> fileImportHistoryRecord =
                          fileImportStatsRepository.findById(fileImportId);
```

The **findById(fileImportId)** method returns null with bunch of stracktraces pointing to the method with the error highlighted above (**at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy146.findById(unknown Source)**) being the one that stands out.

I appreciate any help to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'returns null with this error: at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy146.findById(unknown Source)'

Does the method throw an exception when you try to invoke it? If so, could you share the entire stack trace of the exception?

Or does it return successfully with the result 'null', and there is an exception in the log? If so, what is the entire error message / stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what my issue was, so I'm closing this thread or admin can close it. The issue is that I didn't add a spanner db configuration in the config file.